# Option selecionado

Tags: php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pessoal sou novo em PHP e preciso da ajuda de vocês,
Estou numa tela de edição de um form e estou com dificuldade de deixar selecionado o select que eu fiz no banco.
A consulta retornou como "S", mas está também aparecendo o "N" e o "S".
O correto é aparecer somente o "S" que é o retorno do banco e o "N", caso eu queria alterar para o "N".
O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: [Prefira postar o código, ao invés da imagem.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4612/15089)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se isto for binário (S/N) e o valor recebido está entre os dois, então poderia usar o `selected`, para selecionar um valor já existente.

```
<option value="S" <?= $dado['enc'] == 'S' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>S</option>
<option value="N" <?= $dado['enc'] == 'N' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>N</option>
```

Dessa forma se o valor for `S` ele irá selecionar o `S` já existente. O que você está fazendo é incluir uma nova opção, assim poderá duplicar uma já existente.

*Existe maneiras de não ter que repetir manualmente, dai basta fazer um loop com os valores previamente definidos.*

Comment: Isso mesmo, fiz e deu certo, obrigado.